# Github do not count my commit

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

This is the story.

I have two computers, one is in my home, another is in my office. Both computers have installed Eclipse and connect to the same project of my github account wtih Egit. I find that when I commit on my home computer, my commit will be recorded and display on my contribution graph. However, when I commit on my office computer, commits will not be recorded.

To solve this problem, I delete projects both on my home computer and office computer, and create new project by cloning corresponding project on github.com with identical steps. Furthermore, I use the same eclipse version, they are the newest Mars. However, the problem still remains, commits on home computer will be recorded, and the other will not.

I searched the Internet and can not find the answer. Is there anybody here can help me out? Thanks in advance!

Problem solved. If someone else meet the similar problem, the following link will be quite useful. https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

Comment: problem solved! The answer is I misspelled email address on my office computer. sigh! please delete this problem, it's useless.

Answer (score 4):

Just add your second machines SSH key (assuming you use them) to your account and you should be set. then clone your existing project from the repo, and start working normally. any changes, just commit/push, and from the other machine you can always pull any updates, vice versa.

**Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of the following conditions:**

- The commits were made within the past year.
- The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
- The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
- The commits were made:

  - In the repository's default branch (usually master)
  - In the gh-pages branch (for repositories with Project Pages sites)

In addition, at least one of the following must be true:

- You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization - that owns the repository.
- You have forked the repository.
- You have opened a pull request or issue in the repository.
- You have starred the repository.

Contributions to private repositories will only appear to users who can access those repositories. Those contributions are not rendered for users who cannot access those repositories.

Comment: I don't think it is the SSH key problem, because I have not set SSH key on two computers. And I have read the referred link before, which still do not solve my problem. My  situation is two computers can sync correctly, but when I  commit on one of them, the commit will not be recorded.

Comment: @guzhumoqi are your commits being saved at all from your office computer? i am not talking about the graph. in general is it being saved to your repo?

Comment: Almost all the possibilities described in the above link have been tested, except the one related with Github update mechanisms. I will send an email to support@github.com and find what's really wrong. By the way, the proposer seemed have not solved his problem, because his contribution graph is still almost blank.

Comment: It is very kind of you for posting the related github help content, but I have read that before.